# wait for intent to finish before continuing with the activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I illustrate my problem,
I selected an application that performs a series of operations in quick succession the touch of a button.
each action is represented by an intent to perform a load of an app in the Market or an installation of an external apk.

currently my app does it all in quick succession, but most often give error especially when the intent become many (more than 8)
so I wanted to rewrite the code so that:

- I get a toast,
- the first launch of intent,
- the main activity is paused,
- the term installation or download,
- with the back button returns me to the main app
- that shows me the second toast,
- and start the second intent,
- etc.. etc..

then
there is a way to wait for the end of a first intent to continue?

Comment: Perhaps you want a wizard like application and the ViewFlipper?

Comment: This is just an idea. If I understood you right, your problem is some kind of multi-threading problem, because to many intents are launching a process at the same time. So maybe you could establish some kind of queue, where you schedule the incoming intents and then process them sequentially with another thread.

Answer (score 9):

Use `startActivityForResult()` to start your load / installation or whatever.
Handle the back button event in the started activity to abort the running action.

When your sub-activity has completed you may evaluate the result in `onActivityResult()` in your main activity.

See here for more info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html